# File not found exception on device

Tags: android

I am new to android. By the following code, I am able to successfully create the files in the emulator, but when i run this on my device i get a file not found exception.

```
String l = pwd;
FileOutputStream fos, fos2, fos3;
                    // Log.d("spt", pwd);

                    File registrationinfo = new File(
                            "data/data/com.example.spotter/files/pwd.txt");
                    File registrationinfo2 = new File(
                            "data/data/com.example.spotter/files/uname.txt");
                    File registrationinfo3 = new File(
                            "data/data/com.example.spotter/files/sph.txt");
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(registrationinfo);
                    fos2 = new FileOutputStream(registrationinfo2);
                    fos3 = new FileOutputStream(registrationinfo3);

                    byte buf[] = l.getBytes();
                    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
                        fos.write(buf[i]);
                    }
                    fos.close();
                    byte buf2[] = uname.getBytes();
                    for (int i = 0; i < buf2.length; i++) {
                        fos2.write(buf2[i]);
                    }

                    fos2.close();
                    byte buf3[] = sph.getBytes();
                    for (int i = 0; i < buf3.length; i++) {
                        fos3.write(buf3[i]);
                    }
```

This is my logcat when i run this code on my phone:

```
05-12 13:06:11.425: W/System.err(19066): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.spotter/files/pwd.txt (No such file or directory)
05-12 13:06:11.425: W/System.err(19066):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
05-12 13:06:11.425: W/System.err(19066):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
05-12 13:06:11.425: W/System.err(19066):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
05-12 13:06:11.425: W/System.err(19066):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:66)
05-12 13:06:11.425: W/System.err(19066):    at com.example.spotter.Register.onClick(Register.java:114)
05-12 13:06:11.435: W/System.err(19066):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2533)
05-12 13:06:11.435: W/System.err(19066):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9320)
05-12 13:06:11.435: W/System.err(19066):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-12 13:06:11.435: W/System.err(19066):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-12 13:06:11.435: W/System.err(19066):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
05-12 13:06:11.435: W/System.err(19066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
05-12 13:06:11.435: W/System.err(19066):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 13:06:11.485: W/System.err(19066):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-12 13:06:11.485: W/System.err(19066):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
05-12 13:06:11.485: W/System.err(19066):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
05-12 13:06:11.485: W/System.err(19066):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use

`FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("pwd.txt",  Context.MODE_APPEND | Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);`

instead of

`File registrationinfo = new File("data/data/com.example.spotter/files/pwd.txt");`

to read file data.

From the above code you can use your application's files folder.

Also you can get help from [THIS](http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-23%E2%80%93Writing-and-Reading-Files) link.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the specified file path exists. If not then create it

```
File registrationInfoFolder = new File(
                        "data/data/com.example.spotter/files");

if(!registrationInfoFolder.exists()){
      registrationInfoFolder.mkdirs(); // It will create directory's if not exists
 }
```

Then add your file with FileOutputStream. This happened because there is no files on specified  path.

Comment: the path doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use direct call to `new File("data/data/com.example.spotter/files/pwd.txt");`
Instead of that, call [getFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29): `File registrationinfo = context.getFilesDir("pwd.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you are solve your problem. But you can try add permission in AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```